# Type Error when trying to create URL Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, webrtc

The following line of code breaks in Safari:

```
URL.createObjectURL(stream);
```

Gives me:

```
TypeError: Type error
column: 116
line: 1
message: "Type error"
stack: "createObjectURL@[native code]↵eval code↵eval@[native code]↵_evaluateOn↵_evaluateAndWrap↵evaluate"
```

After searching in net I got recommendation to use `webkitURL` instead of `URL`, but that also throws the same error:

```
webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);

TypeError: Type error
column: 122
line: 1
message: "Type error"
stack: "createObjectURL@[native code]↵eval code↵eval@[native code]↵_evaluateOn↵_evaluateAndWrap↵evaluate"
```

I'm using Safari version 9.0.2 in Mac OS X Yosemite

Comment: Safari  supports webrtc?

Comment: @mido Using [webrtc everywhere](https://github.com/sarandogou/webrtc-everywhere). But, this question isn't related to the plugin. I have that `webrtc` tag just to give a hint how I get the **stream** object

Comment: are you sure the stream object is correct, probably you are getting that error because of that, i just tested with `URL.createObjectURL('aaa')`, got same error...

Comment: `stream` object comes from getUserMedia success function, I haven't modified it any way. And this is a problem in Safari only, Chrome it works fine.

Comment: yeah bec chrome supports gUM by default, here it comes through plugin...